# Form submitting on checkbox onchange doesnt submit the last checked box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, onchange

I have a form with checkboxes and a submit button at the end. When one is selected and the form is submitted it's posted to the server and I can change a query so it filters by that checkboxes value.

HTML & JS

```
<input id="category-1" class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="filter-categories[]" data-fid="1" checked="">
<label for="category-1">Clothing</label>


jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // FILTERS
    $('#form-filter .filter-options input[type="checkbox"]').change(function (e) {
        $('#form-filter').submit();
    });
});
```

If I comment that javascript rule, just select a box and hit submit everything works fine, but if I turn on the javascript I click the link - the form submits, but doesnt change the value. It almost appears like the submit goes faster then the change or something so the value is not changed and sent.

Any1? Thanks!

Comment: In your HTML I assume there's more? Like `<form id="form-filter">` ?

Comment: Yes, `<form id="form-filter" action="" name="filterForm" method="post">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was driving me crazy but I solved it. I somehow thought that there was a jquery error, like maybe the checkbox wasnt selected before I submitted. This was not the case, the problem was in my PHP.

The jQuery `submit()` function doesnt send the submit button's value. In my PHP code I had a check that checked if the submit button was set, in my opinion that was always the case, but it wasnt now. so `if (!empty($_POST['submit-btn'])) {` was false and my script stopped working.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `click` event with checkboxes, because the `change` event occurs before the value of the checkbox is actually changed.

Let me know if it works. Cheers !

```
<input id="category-1" class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="filter-categories[]" data-fid="1" checked="">
<label for="category-1">Clothing</label>


jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // FILTERS
    $('#form-filter .filter-options input[type="checkbox"]').click(function (e) {
        $('#form-filter').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Aaaaargh you almost made my day, but it didnt help :(

Comment: Sorry about that mate. It would help if you could provide us with your PHP code. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing any other functions in form submit event? Normally the form can be submitted on checkbox click like this

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() { 
    if(this.checked) {//just for checking
        //Then trigger the form submit event
        $("#form").trigger('submit');
    } 
    else{
       //do else.
    }
   });
```